# How to remove a prefix from multiple files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-vista, file-rename, batch-rename

I downloaded a lot of videos that are named like `[site.com] filename.mp4` and I wanted to remove the prefix so that they are named like `filename.mp4`.

I tried a batch file with the following code:

```
ren "[site.com] *.mp4" "///////////*.mp4"
```

But the result was `.com] filename.mp4` and can't rename anything beyond the dot, any ideas?

Comment: Seems that the `/` syntax of `ren` is not quite intelligent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=]" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO IF "%%b" neq "" (
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%h IN ("%%b") DO ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a]%%b" "%%h"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Perform a directory scan of the source directory, in `/b` basic mode `/a-d` without directories and tokenise each filename found - the part before the first `]` to `%%a` and the remainder to `%%b`.

If `%%b` is not empty (ie. did not contain `]`) then do nothing, therwise use the default token set (which includes space) and `tokens=0` to strip the leading spaces from `%%b` into `%%h`, then build the original filename and rename.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you. Would there be a way to run it in the same folder as the batch, without rewriting the code each use?

Comment: Set `sourcedir` to `.` which means "current directory"

Comment: I looks like there might be a missing closing `)`. Yes, this probably works, but it is -very- hardcoded to only this exact filename format.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to split on the space in the name.

```
@echo off

:: Pass the file name in as an argument.
:: Split the full path into a directory and filename in case the folder has a space too
set "filepath=%~dp1"
set "filename=%~nx1"

:: Jump into the hosting directory, split the file name after the first space, and jump out
pushd %filepath%
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%filename%") do ren "%filename%" "%%B"
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, a cmd.exe alternative:

```dos
For %A In ("*] *.*") Do @(Set "_=%A"&Call Ren "%A" "%_:*] =%")
```

Answer (score -3):

Use parameter expansion with pattern replacement.

```
f='[site.com] filename.mp4'
mv "$f" "${f/\[site\.com\] /}"
```

Even Windows systems can execute a Bash.

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys

This is a for loop:

```
for f in *.mp4; then
  mv "$f" "${f/\[site\.com\] /}"
done
```

Comment: Title and all the tags cry windows, so why a ?bash? answer?

Comment: Thank you but I can't run that code and the `filename` can change.